# Create a string containing the given number of spaces

Tags: c

I have a variable of type int that should represent the number of spaces. How can I create a string containing as much space characters as the variable value?
For example:

> int Var = 4;

that converted to string should be `"    "`.

Comment: @Antonio Do you actually want a string in memory, or do you simply want to print that number of spaces?

Comment: How do you want the result? Do you have a buffer in which you need it? Do you want freshly malloced buffer which you will have to free? Just print the result?

Comment: `char* output; asprintf(&output, "%*s", var, ""); /* output is now "[4 spaces]" */ free(output);`

Comment: Should the string just containing spaces? Maybe it is better if you share something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *integerToSpaces(unsigned i)
{
    char *str = malloc(i + 1);
    char *ptr = str;

    if(!str) return NULL;
    while(i--)
    {
        *ptr++ = ' ';
    }
    *ptr = 0;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `calloc` + `memset`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. it is an educational version. Showing all the steps ..... and most compilers will optimize it to the memset anyway